# How do I find the average of a set of decibel readings?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

I have a set of data with decibel values of -10.5, -9, -9.5, -9.5, -9, -9. How do I find the average of this data set? I am **not** measuring energy specifically or anything along those lines, only the amplitude of the sound waves. I have taken the simple arithmetic average of this data but I am not really sure if this is right as decibels are on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: What is the purpose of averaging these values?

Comment: I remember exploring the trackless jungles of Sentosa during my expedition to Singapore in 1993!

Comment: @nielsnielsen Hahaha it is a beautiful area

Comment: yes yes, and with perfectly paved paths and food courts!

Answer (score 1):

Well, "technically" speaking, the average of those values is their sum divided by the number of values. Of course you already know that, but I would like to state it just to make the distinction between the average of these values and the average of the corresponding linear values expressed in logarithmic scale (*dB* this is).

In the former case you should do what you have already done. In the latter, you should first convert the logarithmic values to linear, average them and then convert back to logarithmic. In order to convert from *dB* to *linear* you should use the following formula

$$ x = 10^{\frac{dB}{10}} $$

where $x$ is the linear value you "seek" and $dB$ is the decibel value you already have. After that you should average all the values and then convert back to deciBel. The complete formula would look like

$$ y_{ave} = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} 10^{\frac{dB_{i}}{10}}\right)$$

where in this case $y_{ave}$ is in dB, $N$ is the total amount of values you have (in you case this is 6) and $dB_{i}$ is each value.

You could also "simplify" it a bit (not sure the following formula is simpler or not though) to get

$$ y_{ave} = 10 \log_{10} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{N} 10^{\frac{dB_{i}}{10}}\right) - 10 \log_{10} \left( N \right)$$

One note to make here is that depending on the measured quantity (voltage or pressure), you may have to divide by $20$ instead of $10$ (and also multiply in the final formula). The complete formula in this case would be

$$ y_{ave} = 20 \log_{10} \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} 10^{\frac{dB_{i}}{20}}\right)$$

Now, whether the one you seek is the average of the *dB* values you have or the average of the corresponding linear values expressed in *dB* most probably depends on the "application".

Comment: This seems a bit over the top for what I'm doing, IB Extended Essay, but I still might be able to use some of what you said as an explanation (with proper citation of course). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could ask another question if this answer doesn't help you